# Displaying Data Using DataGridView_CellFormatting very slowly

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am displaying data using `DataGridView`. Before displaying data I am validating the "Account Value" (This is one of the columns in the DataGridView) that it exists in the database.

If the value doesn't exist I am changing fore color of that particular cell. This is working fine but is displaying very slow (because it is doing cell by cell).

How can I display data very fast?

This is my code:

```
public void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (e.RowIndex != null)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Count; i++)
       {
           int id = Convert.ToInt32(indexes[i].ToString());
           objPreview.dataGridView1.Rows[id].Cells[1].Style.ForeColor =
               System.Drawing.Color.Red;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `indexes` ? what is the loop for ? Do you  realize that its called for every cell of the grid.

Comment: Here indexes in the list.This List contain account values thous are not in the database. by using that list i am changing fore color of account value.i hope that it is called every cell.

Comment: I believe you need to run it only once try pushing this into the `DataBindingComplete` event and check if it works as you desire.

Comment: Can you give me the idea how can i do using DataBindingComplete.

Comment: Thanks V4Vendetta.i used DataBindingComplete event.This is working fine.